# SQL Server - DDL Trigger to modify Table after its creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, database-trigger

I have a 3rd party program which exports data to SQL Server.
However, such program can not insert, but *drops and recreates* each tables with the data each time it is processed.

There is a specific schema for that.
I need to run modifications on such table on SQL each time it is re-created.

I have been trying using a DDL trigger on Create, which just writes the name of the table to a LOG if it's in the target schema:

```
      CREATE TRIGGER [tCREATE_TABLE] ON DATABASE 
                FOR CREATE_TABLE
            AS     
            DECLARE @data XML;
            DECLARE @schema sysname;
            DECLARE @schema_s nvarchar(128);
            DECLARE @object sysname;
            DECLARE @object_s nvarchar(128);
            DECLARE @eventType sysname;    
            SET @data = EVENTDATA();
            SET @eventType = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]',
                                         'sysname');    
            SET @schema    = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)[1]','sysname');
            SET @schema_s = CAST(@schema as nvarchar(128));
            SET @object    = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]','sysname');
            SET @object_s = CAST(@object as nvarchar(128));   

    -- COMMIT should unlock the table...??
    COMMIT

            IF @schema_s = 'TARGET_SCHEMA'  
                INSERT INTO [TARGET_SCHEMA].[UpdateLOG](TabName,LOAD_UPDATEDATE,LOAD_USER)
                VALUES (@object_s,GETDATE(),CURRENT_USER)
      -- this is the procedure that modifies the target table
        EXEC [ProcessTableProcedure]
              @targettab = @object_s
            GO
```

This works for writing to a log, but as soon as I add call the processing procedure it returns an error.

At the end of the trigger, the modifying procedure won't find the table - since the transaction is not committed yet.

I have put a COMMIT before that, but then nothing happens (procedure is not run).
I assume the trigger ends after the COMMIT...?

Any help?

Comment: Pretty sure there's no need for the `COMMIT` What do you mean by "it won't work"? You didn't post any kind of error message.

Comment: Have you considered using Service Broker? The DDL trigger would send a message, later a procedure would take the message and alter the table. Service Broker is asynchronous and the procedure would run in another transaction after the transaction that created the table  was committed

Comment: @Larnu -- just edited. The procedure simply won't find the table, until the CREATE_TABLE is committed.
However, if I put the COMMIT in the trigger, it will not process the lines that call the procedure

Comment: @JesúsLópez - yes I thought about scheduling, but I wanted it to be istantaneous, as user needs to check immediately the data in a dashboard after uploading